# Wicket Page's ListView LoadableDetachableModel is modified via AJAX call. Page doesn't re-draw

Tags: java, ajax, listview, model, wicket

Consider a page which sub-classes `WebPage`. Its constructor creates
and adds a `WebMarkupContainer`, which contains a `ListView` component
backed by a `LoadableDetachableModel`.

The page also adds two instances of anonymous sub-classes of `AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior` [each overriding the class' `renderHead` and `respond` methods].

The corresponding HTML contains a `<div>` bound by `wicket:id` to the WMC
and a `<table>` with `<tr>`'s bound to the `ListView` component's `ListItems`.

The page displays correctly the first time.

Based on user interaction with the client, the `AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior` in question sets information on the model's model object. The information is intended to be used to change the way a specific `listitem` appears as a `<td>` within the row in the table -- specifically a selected row's text should appear in bold face.

Diagnostic debugger breakpoints and `System.out` info on both sides of
the AJAX call confirm that the behavior's `respond` method is being called correctly and that the model object is being correctly modified.

**The page is never re-drawn automatically.** **Manually re-loading the page
from the browser demonstrates correct behavior.**

I've researched this problem and found a variety of possibly related
solutions, which I've tried, including

- calling `target.add( webMarkupContainer);` from the behavior's
  `respond` method, in conjunction with
- calling `target.appendJavaScript( "window.location.reload();" );` from the `respond` method.
- calling `setResponsePage( this );`, `setResponsePage( Page.class );`, and `setResponsePage( getPage() );` from the `respond` method, as well as from an overridden `onBeforeRender` method on the page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior does not update any components automatically.

Did `target.add( webMarkupContainer)` help? If not, have you called `webMarkupContainer.setOutputMarkupId(true)`?

Comment: I used both, in various combinations, unsuccessfully. I followed your lead re `AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior` and re-did the implementation for the problematic event as an `AjaxEventBehavior`, which now works. Thanks for tip -- I suppose that I missed that useful bit somewhere along the way. If someone doesn't mind, can they point me to relevant reference info where the non-updating nature of the abstract class is described. Thanks again.